# Rails - Object creation for rspec whose class is defined lib/classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write Rspec test case for the `submit` method in the `app/controllers.sample.rb` file.

`User` class is defined in the `lib/classes` folder. `User` object is created in the `session.rb` file in `app/controllers/concerns` which is autoloaded during creation of new session.

The `user` method in the `session.rb` gets the user parameters from another API.

Here I am finding it difficult to create the `User` object using Rspec, it is always returning error at

```
list = user.get_list
```

I have given the sample set of code I have written for the test case.
Could anyone help how to instantiate the `User` object in `concerns/session.rb` from rspec ?

**app/controllers/concerns/session.rb**

```
  def user
    if user
       user
    else
      begin
        rest_resource = RestClient::Resource.new(ENV['SESSION_API'], :verify_ssl => false)
        data = rest_resource.get  Authorization: request.headers['Authorization'] 
      rescue RestClient::Exception => e
        @error = JSON.parse(e.response, symbolize_names: true)
        return nil
      end

      self.user = User.new(current_user,request.headers['Authorization']  )

    end
  end
```

**spec/controllers/rspec_sample.rb**

```
 describe "Submit" do
    it "Submit and expects to succeed" do      
         allow_any_instance_of(Concerns::Session).to receive(:current_user).and_return(name: "test") 

         allow_any_instance_of(Concerns::Session).to receive(:user).and_return(name: "test")
         post :submit, params
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)

    end
  end
```

**app/controllers/sample.rb**

```
def submit
  list = user.get_list  
end
```

**lib/classes/user.rb**

```
class User
  def list    
    return values    
   end  
end
```

Comment: You give too much information that is not related to the problem. First of all you should show the error message.

Comment: `def user
    if user
       user` this is going to confuse everyone, including the ruby interpreter... perhaps you could rename some of the local variables, or you risk confusion or stack overflow...